# Problem using pip3 to install mdanalysis

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I am trying to install mdanalysis for a university project using the command:

`pip3 install --user numpy mdanalysis`

Numpy is already installed, so it works fine, but for mdanalysis I get:

> 

### x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/tmp/pip-install-kpddjyii/mdanalysis_304f5152ac494a7e86bfe16e8b723b16/MDAnalysis/lib/formats -I/home/domenico/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/tmp/pip-install-kpddjyii/mdanalysis_304f5152ac494a7e86bfe16e8b723b16/MDAnalysis/lib/formats/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c MDAnalysis/lib/formats/libdcd.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MDAnalysis/lib/formats/libdcd.o -std=c99 -ffast-math -O3 -funroll-loops -fsigned-zeros
cc1: warning: -fassociative-math disabled; other options take precedence
MDAnalysis/lib/formats/libdcd.c:36:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for mdanalysis
> Running setup.py clean for mdanalysis
> Failed to build mdanalysis
> Installing collected packages: mdanalysis
> Running setup.py install for mdanalysis ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kpddjyii/mdanalysis_304f5152ac494a7e86bfe16e8b723b16/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-kpddjyii/mdanalysis_304f5152ac494a7e86bfe16e8b723b16/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5vlwouu4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/domenico/.local/include/python3.8/mdanalysis

I saw online that I should install python-dev so I did:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

but that package was already installed, so I tried to uninstall and install again with:

`sudo apt autoremove python3-dev`

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

But the problem remained the same. Could someone help? (*I am total noob, so explain it to me like I'm a confused Grampa*)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

After posting this, I found the answer, so I'll post it, in the hopes of helping other confused grampas.
As you can see here:

> "'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-5vlwouu4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /home/domenico/.local/include/python3.8/mdanalysis

It was trying to use the python3.8-dev package so when you do:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`

make sure you install the python-dev package the error message is asking you, in this case:

`sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev`